# How Did Naruto Know The Message His Parents Gave Him Before They Died?

Tags: naruto

From Episode 380,

How did Naruto know Minato's messgae or him?
Naruto said to his father that he already knew the message they gave him while sealing the nine tales in baby Naruto while they both are stabbed by nine tails' nail like a BBQ.
I am very curious.

Thank you for any comment or answer. I will be glad to read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While fighting the Nine-Tails for his chakra, Naruto met the sealed remnants of his mother Kushina inside his seal.
She told him the story of what happened during the Nine-Tails attack on Konoha and also what her and Minatos last words to Naruto were.

That should be in [Episode 249](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Thank_You_(episode)).